# MySQL Select Query - Add two rows and display them as one?

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT        receive.RECEIPT_ID, receive.RECEIPT_DATE, supplier.NAME, item.NAME AS Expr2, receive_item.PRICE, receive_item.QTY, (receive_item.QTY - IFNULL(delivery_item.QTY, 0)) AS 'REMAINED QTY.'
FROM            receive_item INNER JOIN
                         receive ON receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = receive.RECEIPT_ID INNER JOIN
                         supplier ON receive.SUPPLIER_ID = supplier.ID INNER JOIN
                         item ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = item.ID INNER JOIN
                         po ON receive.PO_NUMBER = po.PO_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         delivery_item ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = delivery_item.ITEM_ID AND receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = delivery_item.RECEIVE_ID
```

the table below is from a very complicated select query above

```
ID      RECEIPT_DATE  SUPP_NAME      ITEM                      PRICE  QTY  QTY_REMAINED 

1   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER PIPE 42MM                       245.00   1   0
2   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER PIPE 15MM                       350.00   1   0
3   2012-01-22  MANCO   "RUBBER INSULLATION HOSE 35mm x 1"""   478.00   1   0
4   2012-01-22  MANCO   DEFROST HEATER 9mmx215cm 220Vx800W     5000.00  10  1
5   2012-01-22  MANCO   DEFROST HEATER 9mmx215cm 220Vx800W     5000.00  10  9
6   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER ELBOW 90  42MM                  100.00   1   0
7   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER ELBOW 90  12MM                  200.00   3   0
8   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER ELBOW 45  28MM                  3000.00  4   0
9   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER PIPE 15MM                       4.00 3   2   0
```

I need a select query that combines ID 4 and 5 so the table will appear like this;

```
ID      RECEIPT_DATE  SUPP_NAME      ITEM                      PRICE  QTY  QTY_REMAINED 

1   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER PIPE 42MM                       245.00   1   0
2   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER PIPE 15MM                       350.00   1   0
3   2012-01-22  MANCO   "RUBBER INSULLATION HOSE 35mm x 1"""   478.00   1   0
4   2012-01-22  MANCO   DEFROST HEATER 9mmx215cm 220Vx800W     5000.00  10  0
5   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER ELBOW 90  42MM                  100.00   1   0
6   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER ELBOW 90  12MM                  200.00   3   0
7   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER ELBOW 45  28MM                  3000.00  4   0
8   2012-01-22  MANCO   COPPER PIPE 15MM                       4.00 3   2   0
```

So, in the desired table, `QTY_REMAINED` for `ID 4` is appeared as `0` not 1 and 9

I think the query has to do something like `10 - ( 10- 1 ) + ( 10 - 9)` to make the value `0`.

Is is possible to do it? or should I do it in program?

Comment: There seems to be sth wrong about ID in either of tables, can you recheck please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to group all values with common RECEIPT_DATE, SUPP_NAME, ITEM and PRICE values. You could then try this:

```
SELECT
  receive.RECEIPT_DATE, supplier.NAME, item.NAME AS Expr2, receive_item.PRICE,
  receive_item.QTY, 
  receive_item.QTY - IFNULL(sum(delivery_item.QTY), 0)) AS 'REMAINED QTY.'
FROM
  receive_item
INNER JOIN
  receive ON receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = receive.RECEIPT_ID 
INNER JOIN
  supplier ON receive.SUPPLIER_ID = supplier.ID 
INNER JOIN
  item ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = item.ID 
INNER JOIN
  po ON receive.PO_NUMBER = po.PO_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  delivery_item ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = delivery_item.ITEM_ID 
  AND receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = delivery_item.RECEIVE_ID 
GROUP BY receive.RECEIPT_DATE, supplier.NAME, item.NAME AS Expr2, 
  receive_item.PRICE, receive_item.QTY;
```

You'll note I removed the receive.RECEIPT_ID. This appears to be a unique id so you cannot aggregate it or you'd have an invalid result. Since you're looking at quantity remaining stats I also wonder if you want the receipt date column, but that really depends on the purpose of your query. This current one would allow you to track the quantity remaining on a daily basis.

Quick note: I did some testing of the ordering of IFNULL(sum()) vs sum(IFNULL()) and it did not appear to affect the results, which is as I would expect. You still might want to try both ways sanity check the results as you'll be working on a larger data set than I was.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get remaining total quantity of items to deliver.
Instead of left-joining `delivery-item` you should left-join it grouped by `ITEM_ID` and `RECEIVE_ID` with sum of `QTY` for every group.

```
SELECT        receive.RECEIPT_ID, receive.RECEIPT_DATE, supplier.NAME,
              item.NAME AS Expr2, receive_item.PRICE, receive_item.QTY,  
              (receive_item.QTY - IFNULL(delivery_group.QTY, 0)) AS 'REMAINED QTY.'
FROM            
    receive_item 
INNER JOIN
    receive ON receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = receive.RECEIPT_ID 
INNER  JOIN
    supplier ON receive.SUPPLIER_ID = supplier.ID 
INNER JOIN
    item ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = item.ID 
INNER JOIN
    po ON receive.PO_NUMBER = po.PO_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ( SELECT ITEM_ID, RECEIVE_ID, SUM(QTY) AS QTY
    FROM delivery_item
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID, RECEIVE_ID ) delivery_group
ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = delivery_group.ITEM_ID 
AND receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = delivery_group.RECEIVE_ID
```